# Why does a web app container access mysql container within the same docker report a timeout error

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-container

- Bug description:

> This error is reported when a web-app container in docker accesses the mysql(version 8) container.

- Error log:

```js
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:906) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:831) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:354) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:202) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) [HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:554) [HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158) [spring-jdbc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116) [spring-jdbc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79) [spring-jdbc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction.openConnection(SpringManagedTransaction.java:82) [mybatis-spring-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
    at org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction.getConnection(SpringManagedTransaction.java:68) [mybatis-spring-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.getConnection(BaseExecutor.java:336) [mybatis-3.4.5.jar!/:3.4.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.prepareStatement(SimpleExecutor.java:84) [mybatis-3.4.5.jar!/:3.4.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:62) [mybatis-3.4.5.jar!/:3.4.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:324) [mybatis-3.4.5.jar!/:3.4.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:156) [mybatis-3.4.5.jar!/:3.4.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:109) [mybatis-3.4.5.jar!/:3.4.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:83) [mybatis-3.4.5.jar!/:3.4.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:148) [mybatis-3.4.5.jar!/:3.4.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:141) [mybatis-3.4.5.jar!/:3.4.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:77) [mybatis-3.4.5.jar!/:3.4.5]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:433) [mybatis-spring-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy53.selectOne(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectOne(SqlSessionTemplate.java:166) [mybatis-spring-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:82) [mybatis-3.4.5.jar!/:3.4.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:59) [mybatis-3.4.5.jar!/:3.4.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55.selectByName(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at com.springcloud.example.service.UserService.selectPeople(UserService.java:15) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.springcloud.example.controller.UserResource.getPlayer(UserResource.java:23) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) [spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) [spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) [spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893) [spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:807) [spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061) [spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961) [spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) [spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:747) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:850) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
    ... 89 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
    ... 91 common frames omitted
```

- The network configuration between web-app container and mysql container

```
[user@localhost ~]# docker network inspect container-docker 
[
    {
        "Name": "container-docker",
        "Id": "f68a31fdd2c7287a13a12b29f014dddab30641a758cc3d32163f2f291365ca03",
        "Created": "2020-11-17T12:04:07.347541114+08:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.19.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.19.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "704dc6e85dfcf009f0af8b7fe433bab6e1105a286caf87a234f5042b478ca587": {
                "Name": "mysql",
                "EndpointID": "003a4848c099660cbcc93a0b553a30fad8aff9ff9cfb8e777d070e7fb56k726h",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "c9550a5d37a20fe2e3457be898c860758da06e20d134449e89ecb4c22c1md93e": {
                "Name": "web-app",
                "EndpointID": "7e8e1ac94f53151cb2fccc81a15838c63398587a4042bb541874ae6da37m9d42",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

- Container connectivity：

```
[user@localhost ~]# docker exec web-app ping mysql 
PING mysql (172.19.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.19.0.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.090 ms
64 bytes from 172.19.0.3: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms
64 bytes from 172.19.0.3: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.179 ms
64 bytes from 172.19.0.3: seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.071 ms
64 bytes from 172.19.0.3: seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.192 ms
64 bytes from 172.19.0.3: seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.131 ms
64 bytes from 172.19.0.3: seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.073 ms
64 bytes from 172.19.0.3: seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.192 ms
```

- The application.yml of my springboot project:

```
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/user?characterEncoding=utf-8&connectTimeout=1000&socketTimeout=3000&autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=GMT%2B8&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
    username: user
    password: pwd
```

- In addition, I can access mysql container by changing the url of datasource to "jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/user..."

#### Thank you very much for taking the time to review and answer

Comment: try to add in your host file the mysql ip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solve the problem through the following process.

1. If you turn on the **firewall**, you need to do the following steps：

- view firewall NAT forwarding

```js
firewall-cmd --query-masquerade
```

If result:no,then:

```js
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-masquerade --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

- turn on IPv4 forwarding:

```js
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
sysctl -p
```

2. If you just want to access through the **container name**, that's it,but
   if you still want to access through the host IP address,you should:

- get container-docker interface name:

```js
[admin@localhost ~]# ifconfig
br-4cf89773q8e0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.19.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.19.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:77ff:fe34:3599  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:77:34:35:99  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 26  bytes 1780 (1.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 46  bytes 4731 (4.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:36ff:fe73:a500  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:36:73:a5:00  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 770  bytes 90572 (88.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 733  bytes 238016 (232.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

- allow network packets to host from your docker bridge network

```js
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --change-interface=br-4cf89773q8e0
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql URL formate is :--

```
jdbc:mysql://<HOST>:<PORT>/<DATABASE>
```

in your case hostname is mysql that is wrong. Please provide correct hostname n check once.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,the application deployed in docker can be configured like this:

`jdbc:mysql://CONTAINER:<PORT>/<DATABASE>`
Of course which way you said is right, but it’s just not the way I want

Comment: you give the "ip address" in place of HOSTNAME (Ip address in the sense where you have mysql server and there should be connectivity.

Comment: if you wanna run locally in your system then you can give "localhost".

Comment: I know what you mean,but it's not the way i want to run this web-app in docker

Comment: then how u wanna run?

Comment: have you run the image? if yes what did you give name there , same you can put here in place of hostname.

Comment: Yes,i did.did you see the container connectivity in my question details,it means two image are already running, i appreciate your time,but i think you must first understand docker before answering this question.

Comment: saw that, you are not mapping correct way ..don't way how you have created image?